# CSS / jQuery - Como selecionar o próximo elemento após a 'main'?

Tags: jquery, css

Basicamente, estou dando um margin-top no primeiro conteúdo após o cabeçalho, de acordo com o tamanho do cabeçalho.

O problema é que cada página do site possui elementos diferentes após a main (div ou section). Como posso selecionar o 'elemento-filho' da main mesmo sendo diferente em cada página.

('main > div') e ('main > section') funcionam, porém a margem é aplicada em ambas, o correto seria apenas no bloco abaixo do cabeçalho...

O site possui muitas páginas, preciso de apenas um script se possível, ou se tiver alguma solução em css também aceito.

Comment: @renan Não, isso selecionaria qualquer elemento que estiver "1 nível" abaixo da main. Enquanto da maneira que o @Genos respondeu `main > *:first-child` funciona corretamente, pois seleciona apenas o primeiro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seletor `first-child` seleciona elementos que sejam o primeiro filho de seu pai. E o seletor `*` seleciona qualquer elemento.

Logo, você poderia fazer algo como:

```
main > *:first-child {
    /* Estilos */
}
```

Esta expressão selecionaria o primeiro filho de main, independente de tipo.

Edição:

Se você quer que somente `section` ou `div` sejam selecionados, ao invés de qualquer elemento também é possível:

```
main > div:first-child, main > section:first-child {
    /* Estilos */
}
```